# how to make it like jquery?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've just created a small js framework like underscoer.js. The method calls are carried out by `mc_.grep([1,2,3,4], function(val){ return val > 2; });`. How can I make it more like jQuery style `mc_(var).grep(func..).map(func..);` ? Any ideas? And also how can I make the library better?

https://github.com/awesomegamer/mc_-js-library

Comment: You'll need to post more complete code. But this may be better off on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include my library code. I put up the github link.

Comment: @lightning - just so you know, regarding your most recent post that was downvoted today, and which you removed voluntarily. If you grab the relevant bit of code and insert it into your question, readers will have something in front of them to assist you on, and you'll qualify for having done 'prior research'. However if you hyperlink to a repo (as here also) it gives readers a lot of code to sift through. Make it easy for them, and narrow down the question as much as you can `:)`. Aside: questions that are paragraphed, spell-checked and markdown-hyperlinked are less likely to be downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Your function should return a wrapped object
function Wrap(list) {
    return Object.create(Wrap).constructor(list)
}

// set the list as an internal property
Wrap.constructor = function (list) {
    this._list = list
    return this
}

// map function works in one of two ways, if it has an internal _list property
// then it was called as Wrap(list).map(...)
// then call the map function on it with the arguments
// store the result as a new list as _list
// return this so you can chain
//
// If it's not then it was used as Wrap.map(list, ...)
// extract the arguments using [].slice(arguments, 1)
// then return the result of invoking it
Wrap.map = function (list) {
    if (this._list) {
        this._list = this._list.map.apply(this._list, arguments)
        return this
    } else {
        return list.map.apply(list, [].slice.call(arguments, 1))
    }
}

// Wrappers need an unwrap method
// Wrap(list).map(...).filter(...).reduce(...).get()
Wrap.get = function () { 
    return this._list
}
```

Comment: +1, but some explanation for the OP would be great

Comment: Why he no read the code and just understand it by inspection :(

Comment: OP probably can understand it by inspection, but understanding how the code works doesn't give complete insight into _why_ you did it that way.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean that you want to chain the function calls every time you return from a function you must return you must return something that is wrapped inside the basic object that is at the heart of your framework so that you can call the next method on the returned object.

For example (this is very basic) the `$('#someid')` call is returned like this by jQuery

```
this.length = 1;
    this[0] = elem;
}

this.context = document;
this.selector = selector;
return this;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a good article available on wikipedia called ["Method chaining"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

An *oversimplified* example of chaining, also available as a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RPjxR/) (just open console with <kbd>F12</kbd> to see the result) would be as follows:

```
var a = {
    b: function () {
        console.log('b');
        // Make method chainable:
        return this;
    },
    c: function () {
        console.log('c');
        // Make method chainable:
        return this;
    }
};

// Now you can do:
a.b().c();​
```

I recommend taking a look at the [annotated source code of underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html) to avoid the feeling *"oh damn, I've spent so much time reinventing a wheel"*.

How to improve? There's only one way I know: make it useful.

Comment: I do use underscore but I wanted to create one of my own for practice purposes. Thnx for the reply!